# Upgrading to 4.7.7 gives Error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Tags: upgrade, error

I am trying to upgrade from 4.6.16 to 4.7.7, although the upgrading process completes, and drupal site works perfectly fine, as soon as I go to civicrm URL i receive this error message. This happened when I tried to upgrade to 4.7.0 too.

`Error: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

I have followed upgrade instruction perfectly, all file permission is fine. Anyone knows where the problem may be?

**Update: Log from civicrm**

```
Feb 04 08:57:46  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Your database is not configured for version 4.7.1
    [code] => 
)


Feb 04 08:57:46  [info] $backTrace = #0 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(366): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(191): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Your database is not configured for version 4.7.1")
#2 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(81): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->runFinish()
#3 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->run((Array:2), NULL)
#4 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#5 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade")
#8 /www/demo/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:1))
#9 /www/demo/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}
```

UPDATE 2: Log when visited the upgrade url after the error message. Now i have Tried with 4.7.7, but still no luck.

```
 backTrace

#0 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(367): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(98): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.7")
#2 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(73): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->runIntro()
#3 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->run((Array:2), NULL)
#4 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#5 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 /www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(454): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("upgrade")
#8 /www/demo/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:1))
#9 /www/demo/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}
```

PHP Error message is quiet large one so its on pastebin
http://pastebin.com/wTZyNEf6

Comment: Have you checked /sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.[longhashstring].log.[timestamp]? Answer you're looking for, is, most likely, there.Or, at least, an useful cue.

Comment: i have added the log

Comment: Two questions:  Is demo.com really your site, or have you done a find/replace on the domain name?  The IP doesn't seem to resolve to anything from here, nor does it seem to be publicly accessible.  Q2:  Have you cleared the FastCGI cache?  Something seems to be stuck on trying to go directly to the upgrade routine immediately.

Comment: yes, I have replaced the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I had couple of conflicting extensions that were causing the problem.
one is UK Postcode look up and other is CiviRules.
Once that is uninstalled, upgrade went smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like step 11 failed.  What happens when you visit:
* Point your web browser to the following URL (you should already be logged in to Drupal with administrator-level permissions):

```
*- If "clean URLs" are enabled
http://<your_drupal_home>/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1

*- If "clean URLs" are NOT enabled
http://<your_drupal_home>/?q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1
```

Do you see errors after this?

(Sorry, I mixed posts in my head and missed the Drupal piece.  First version was for WordPress.)

Comment: Do you know what the Drupal equivalent of that url would be?  Tapash's backtrace indicates Drupal with 'sites/all/modules' in the urls.

Comment: I realized that and was apparently editing when you posted.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Hi Allen, Sorry for delayed response. I have updated the post with log when I visit the URL you have provided. This time I tried to upgrade to 4.7.7. and its still the same.

Comment: I have update the post with  PHP error log as well.